# Greasemonkey script to show current daily reputation cap

Tags: discussion, daily-reputation-limit, userscript

**Important**: this no longer works and needs a patch; [see my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/greasemonkey-script-to-show-current-daily-reputation-cap/51783#51783).

---

I've just finished creating yet another greasemonkey script.

This script will display your reputation earned today and the time till the next cycle begins. If you have reached your daily reputation limit, the text will turn red.

**EDIT:** Fixed a bug with the countdown.

[image: Screenshot]

[http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/55025](https://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/55025)

Comment: I noticed the bug last night...was going to mention it today (well, I guess I just did) but seeing that you already caught it I'll just shut up. :)

Comment: Very very nice script. I got burned today for going over the limit today and lost probably about 70 or so potential rep.

Comment: Great script, but it seems to have recently stopped working. Has the activity page changed its output?

Comment: @ire_and_curses: The script has been fixed.

Comment: It appears the script is broken now?

Comment: can this please be moved to http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts as necessary? Or flag for deletion.

Answer (score 4):

This no longer works but I fixed it. Find the line with `var separator` and replace it with:

```
var separator = logout_link.parent().prev().find('span:last');
```

Also, would anyone be interested if I were to fix the reputation cap coloring too? Right now it colors it in red if >= 200, but that's wrong with the new changes.

Answer (score 3):

Nice work. I love the live countdown too.

Comment: well, if it's greasemonkey approved, it's good enough for me. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've rewritten [@Nick Craver's Chrome port](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/greasemonkey-script-to-show-current-daily-reputation-cap/57813#57813) to work with the latest SE UI changes.

The latest version of it will (for now) live as a [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/825973).

**Edit** <s>just came across a few bugs in this version; update pending.</s> fix't.

Comment: consider posting it on [StackApps](http://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts)

Comment: I consider Nick to be the original creator of the script, so I'd sooner let him do it (and receive the credit).

Comment: thanks, it works great!

Comment: It seems to consider only 200 as a cap and doesnt take into consideration all accepted answers. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @KarthikT not sure what you mean. 200 rep *is* the daily cap, ignoring accepted answers and bounties.

Comment: @MattBall I mean that the daily cap is actually 200 + accepted answers + bounties. i.e if I have 3 accepted answers, the daily cap is 245, but the count goes red at 200 anyway which is missleading.

Answer (score 1):

First, nice work on this Andrew, the interface for this is simple and very useful.  (Also very interested in that iPhone app).

In case anyone else can use this, I made some slight adjustments to Andrew's script to make a Chrome version (for myself really, this thing's handy...but if others can benefit have at it).  It doesn't work in both...sorry not a Firefox daily user anymore :)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           SO Show Today's Reputation
// @namespace      SO_TODAY_REP
// @description    Shows today's reputation score and time till new session begins.
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.textContent = "(" + topBar.toString() + ")();";
  document.body.appendChild(script);

  function topBar() {
    $(function() {
      var logout_link = $("#topbar a:first");

      if(logout_link.length) {
        $("#topbar").css('max-width', '1000px');
        var link = $("#topbar a[href^='/users/recent/']:first");
        var today = new Date();
        var UTCtoday = today.getUTCFullYear() + '-' + GM_fixNumber(today.getUTCMonth()+1) + '-' + GM_fixNumber(today.getUTCDate());
        var url = (link.attr('href').match(/^[^?]+/))[0] + '?StartDate=' + UTCtoday + '&EndDate=' + UTCtoday;

        $('<span></span>').load(url + " div#tabs a[href^='/users/recent/'][href*='tab=reputation']:first span.bounty-indicator-tab:first" , function() {
          var today_rep = $(this).text();
          $(this).remove();

          if(!today_rep) today_rep = 0;

          var today_rep_int = parseInt(today_rep, 10);

          var separator = logout_link.parent().prev().find('span:last');
          separator.clone().insertBefore(separator);

          var rep_score = $('<span class="reputation-score"></span>').text(' ' + today_rep).insertBefore(separator);

          var time_score = $('<span class="badgecount"></span>').insertBefore(separator);

          if(today_rep_int >= 200) {
            rep_score.css('color', '#BB0000');
            time_score.css('color', '#BB8888');
          }

          var timer = function() {
            var now = new Date();
            var nextSess = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+1, 0, 0-now.getTimezoneOffset(), 0);

            if(nextSess.getTime() <= now.getTime()) {
              nextSess.setDate(nextSess.getDate()+1);
            }

            var diff = parseInt((nextSess.getTime() - now.getTime()) / 1000, 10);

            var hours = parseInt((diff / 3600) % 24, 10);
            var minutes = parseInt((diff % 3600) / 60, 10);
            var seconds = diff % 60;

            var settext = GM_fixNumber(hours) + ':' + GM_fixNumber(minutes) + '.' + GM_fixNumber(seconds);

            time_score.text(' - ' + settext + ' ');
          };

          timer();

          setInterval(timer, 1000);
        });
      }      
    });
    function GM_fixNumber(num) {
      if(num < 10) return '0' + num;
      return num;
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the Chrome port.

Comment: The [recent removal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/) of the logout link from the top bar broke this script. Here's my fix for it: https://gist.github.com/825973. Just needed to change the `logout_link` selector.

Comment: @Matt - I made the same change when we moved the logout, forgot to update this - thanks!

Comment: Dangit, the UI changes broke this durned thing _again_

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if someone would rewrite it to use `/reputation` instead of `/users/`.

Comment: `/reputation` already reports the days you met the cap and exceeded the cap.  Just look at the bottom of the report.

Comment: Currently, it takes your currently earned reputation from your user page. I was asking if it could be rewritten to use `/reputation`, which is a smaller page.

Comment: I rewrote @Nick Craver's Chrome version to work with the latest UI changes. See my answer.