# Provide a readout of how much rep remains in the daily cap

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

If you've started a bounty, it's difficult to tell how close you are to the daily rep cap. Usually the reputation tab and the "Today" button allow this, but at first when I had only 50 rep for 7 upvotes I almost thought there was a bug.

It'd be nice if there was a quick and simple way to check the rep cap count, to ensure there aren't cases like this.

Consider the following image:
[SO Rep Page http://billy-oneal.com/forums/4-14-2010%2012-20-48%20PM.png](http://billy-oneal.com/forums/4-14-2010%2012-20-48%20PM.png)

**EDIT: It seems this is done now.**

```
 3   2679717 (-1)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 9   2653018 (100)
 2   2653018 (10)
 2   2679922 (10)
 2   2682904 (10)
 1   2679922 (15)
 2   2684786 (5)
 2   2686171 (10)
 2   2686171 (10)
 2   2686171 (10)
 2   2686171 [6] <-- Note square brackets  instead of parenthesis indicate cap
 2   2686171 [0]
 2   2686171 [0]
 2   2650311 [0]

** total rep 4783 :)
```

Comment: -1 for the blatant lack of freehand circles!

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: Why freehand circles? What's the point of SnagIt if you aren't going to use it properly? :)

Comment: -1 for electorate badge!

Comment: (-1) for the reasons in my response.

Comment: Can some moderator put [status-completed] on this? It's certainly done.

Comment: Removed my downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reputation cap is designed to keep the reputation range a little closer, so that users can't just run away from the pack.

It is known that it will occasionally discourage people from answering questions, but that is not the intention. Your solution will actively discourage people from answering questions. The only reason anyone would need to know if they are at the cap is if they are curious, or if they intend to act on it. If they are curious, then they can do the math. If they intend to act on it, then they are clearly going to say either "I'm under the cap, I should answer another question" or "I've hit the cap, I don't need to answer anything else today" both of which are not behaviours that should be encouraged.

The goal of the community is to have people answer as many questions as they have (completely voluntary) time for. Even if you've hit the cap, you can still get reputation later on questions you answer, and if your question is marked as accepted, it is also exempt from the cap.

Publishing *explicitly* that a user has reached the cap has no upside, and it has the possible downside of discouraging participation.

Comment: @devinb: I'm not saying it has to be in an obvious location. But making it obtainable *somewhere* would be nice.

Comment: (Sorry for double comment): To be clear, the only reason I want this is that it was very confusing to get 7 upvotes for an answer and get only 50 rep for it. Usually checking the rep page tells you instantly, "Well, you hit the cap", and life goes on. But without that, I almost came here and reported a bug -- even though the system is behaving as designed it doesn't appear that way to the end user.

Comment: I understand that, however, I'm still against it for the reasons I mentioned. Maybe your rep for the day could be in another colour if you've hit the cap. But I don't think there should be a running counter. That would just lend itself towards counters of how much rep you LOST due to the cap, and that would be ACTIVELY discouraging participation.

Comment: @devinb: I would agree with that -- it doesn't have to be a readout. But some sort of way of saying "this is not a bug, you have hit the reputation cap" is the main thing I'm looking for. A readout seems like the simplest way to accomplish that but your solution is perhaps better. +1

Answer (score 1):

This lovely Grease Monkey [script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/greasemonkey-script-to-show-current-daily-reputation-cap) works wonders for me!

Comment: Unfortunately I use Chrome, not Firefox.

Comment: Not a problem! http://www.mychromeaddons.com/chrome-addon-greasemetal-greasemonkey-for-chrome/

Comment: Hmm.. that seems an enormous enormous hack. +1 though.

Answer (score 0):

On days where you haven't created a bounty, you can do this easily by totalling the amount of reputation you've earned today (by clicking 'today' and viewing the number in the reputation tab label), and subtracting 15 for every answer accepted today (and 2 for every post you've marked as accepted), since they don't count towards the cap.

Otherwise, simply head over to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation and check the total at the bottom, for today's reputation, making adjustments for accepted answers as above and also adding back in the bounty you set.

Comment: It'd still be nice to not have to correct for such things manually though :)

Comment: @Billy: agreed! Perhaps someone will whip up a greasemonkey script that will provide this data (it may require calling the new API, rather than screenscraping your profile page).

Answer (score 0):

```
javascript:p=0;$('.upvote b').map(function(k,v){p+=+v.textContent;});alert(p)
```

Comment: Erm.. sorry, but what does that do?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: As far as I can tell, prints out 0.

Comment: @Billy: Go to the rep page, put that in the location bar, hit Enter. Tested on Firefox 3.6 only, which is what I needed anyway ;).

Comment: KennyTM -- that's not my confusion. My confusion is that it's just a snipped of JS. What do I do with it?