# Can we raise awareness of unused votes?

Tags: feature-request, voting, header

A lot of stack sites (most? all?) aren't getting as many votes as I'd like to see them get.  I don't want to drop a carrot in front of people that encourages them to give meaningless votes just to reach some threshold, but it would be nice to make voting habits more visible so that those of us who *intend* to vote more actually *do*.

How can we raise awareness for those who just need that mental post-it-note without annoying everybody?

I suggest we add a vote-o-meter (a small bar that fills up as votes are cast) in the header bar so that users can see how much of their daily vote allotment they have used.  It may give those of us who want to develop better voting habits the visual nudge we need to remember to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think users should be trying to run up to the limit of their number of votes for a given day. The number of vote limiter is in fact designed to *prevent* what your solution would lead to -- that is, indiscriminate voting. I'd much rather see users not voting all that much, but having their votes be carefully considered, than users just using votes to use all their votes for a day.

If a user doesn't cast as many votes, it's because they haven't seen enough things worth voting on, not that they don't know that they have more votes.

**EDIT**: Also note that [similar proposals](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46649/provide-a-readout-of-how-much-rep-remains-in-the-daily-cap) have been shot down in the past.... :)

Comment: Personally, I find myself just forgetting to vote.  Sometimes I'll remember and hit the back button, but I definitely don't vote as much as I intend to.

Comment: I'm not sure that example is on point -- a rep counter isn't a reminder of a particular action we want people to take -- a vote indicator is. That said, I'd be worried about a badge or rep incentive causing some indiscriminate voting, but I'm not convinced that a gentle reminder in this or some other form would do the same thing.