# Logout link now missing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, logout

The logout link is now missing for Stack Overflow as well as meta. Haven't check out the other sites.

[image: Meta Screenshot]

[image: SO Screenshot]

Any particular issue here?

Comment: guys, April Fool's not anywhere close :(

Comment: Oh man, I saw the empty bars up top thinking [this was a related problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79307/header-divider-doesnt-display-properly-after-approving-suggested-edits).  Didn't even notice that there was no logout button until you brought it up.  :)

Comment: Once you are in, THERE IS NO WAY OUT.... :)

Comment: We could logout? And get a life too... ;-).

Comment: Maybe it's a sign that we're on SO for way too long.

Comment: same thing by me

Comment: Should Stack Overflow be renamed The Hotel California?

Comment: very good had the same problem

Comment: There was a logout button before?  I'm kind of surprised by the number of people who actually noticed this.  ;)

Comment: "The Hotel California"? USA-joke? someone mind explaining?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: It's a reference to the song "Hotel California" by the Eagles, which features the lyric "You can check out any time you like, but you can never leave." (followed by an awesome guitar solo, I might add).

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: Some [interpretations of Hotel California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotel_California_%28song%29#Interpretation).

Comment: @mauris - i'm from USA and don't understand the joke either, no worries bro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To supplement Rebecca Chernoff's answer:

[image]

Comment: Not even just supplementing, you are correcting!  The logout link isn't on your profile anymore.

Comment: This screenshot is outdated. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210187/142481 for updated information

Answer (score 13):

The link has been moved to your user profile.  Click on your username at the top of the page and you will see the link there.

Comment: true+valid. but are we still keeping the logout link at the top? Surely we can have an announcement to tell people about it (RUP's managing change). We can remove the extra gray bar to prevent confusion.

Comment: IMO it's a grave mistake: people are used to have the logout link anywhere. It will scare many people away from SO, apart of making even more people really angry.

Comment: IMHO it's okay for me (and some people) because I NEVER use stack overflow on computers other than my own. It's just that the Logout link is a very common element for many websites when the user is authenticated.

Comment: A very small percentage of people use the link.

Comment: @Rebecca: Still, some kind of announcement for such things would be highly appreciated. I also wondered why that link suddenly disappeared, and I was pretty sure it was a temporary bug. It was just luck that I found this post! (EDIT: OK, I see that at least it's on the "Recent feature changes", but many people on the other .sx sites don't know about that one!)

Comment: @HendrikVogt, [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) contains new and changed features.

Comment: @Rebecca it's more of a change-then-announce. IMHO I think the community prefers announce-then-change, no matter how small the change is (: thanks for the link too

Comment: I think this is an error, how can I teach someone to always log out of sites, if some sites don't have a log out link.

Comment: For goodness sake, please bring the link back to where it was.

Comment: For those thinking this is a bad idea, I would agree.  _But_, it feels like there is another change coming soon to replace the button (and fill in that spot).  I say, be patient and let the team do their thing.  If after a week or two, there doesn't seem to be any progress, then we can start whining.  :)

Comment: The link didn't really work well for me since the [global network auto-login](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/) was introduced: I would often be logged back in when visiting some other SE site, and then coming back to the one I logged out from. Boldly clearing cookies and the HTML5 Local Storage works better for me.

Comment: The only time I logged out from StackOverflow, was when I wanted to know, which cookies it sets for guests and for users ... good change.

Comment: hey guys, I just calculated. Say if we have 100000 active users on SO, and each user loads 30 pageviews each day, by removing the link `<a href="/users/logout?returnurl=/">log out</a>`, we save 134.46807 mb worth of bandwidth every day! That's more than 4GB each month. #soMoneySavingTechniques

Comment: @thephpdeveloper, did you take the gzip content encoding into account? That's [a factor 6](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http://stackoverflow.com?http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET) for the homepage!

Comment: hahaha @Arjan good one.

Comment: What a retarded thing to do. Almost every site on the web shows the logout link on every page. Making things harder is the right way to go :

Comment: Logging out is the fastest way to temporarily not ignore your ignore-tags. It is still useful. And from a security point of view, logging out should be one of those things that are impossible to miss from a user interface, no matter how infrequently used.

Comment: @Rebecca Chernoff: update?

Comment: Deleting cookies seems to be the only effective way out. The log out link, when I eventually found it, doesn't even work for me.

Comment: In fact this answer is flat out wrong. The drop down does not appear on stackexchange.com. There is literally no way to log out other than deleting cookies as far as I can see.

Comment: I need to change my password. How do I logout to test the new login?