# S.O logout where did it go

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logout link now missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing)

is it me or the S.O logout button really disappeared???[image]

Comment: +1 for the very professional screen shot :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's on your account page:
[image]

But I have no clue why it went there...

Comment: OH! after staring for about 5min i finally managed to locate it :p

Comment: and there is an empty | | sign where the log-out used to be ... is it appearing at your end too?

Comment: @3nigma: yep, it is. Maybe you could report *that* as a bug.

Answer (score 4):

You can find it in your account page.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/logout?returnurl=/

Comment: Why could it not stay in the title bar like it was before?