# Can the log out link be removed at Area 51?

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, logout

[Logout link now missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing), but not on Area 51. :-(

Comment: Actually, it's missing on A51 Discussion Zone, but still there on A51.

Comment: It should be removed, I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Area 51's log-out link is now on the user page, to be consistent with the rest of the network.