# Can we have a log out link on our meta profile?

Tags: feature-request, meta, logout

There doesn't seem to be a **log out** link on our meta profiles, is this by design?

[image]
<sub>(source: [screencast.com](https://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/3685efe5-1aba-4f73-bfb6-13e2019de975/2011-02-25_1605.png))</sub>

Related: [Logout link now missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing)

Comment: I see one in mine.

Comment: The log out link appears on my meta profile.

Comment: [None on Meta.SU](http://content.screencast.com/users/TomWij/folders/Jing/media/3685efe5-1aba-4f73-bfb6-13e2019de975/2011-02-25_1605.png), or does it still have to roll out?

Comment: Don't forget that except for here meta profiles aren't "real" profiles - you can't edit them for example.

Comment: I don't have one.

Comment: Actually, @ChrisF, if you're a moderator, you *can* see the logout link. I can see it on Gaming Meta, for example. You... also can apparently edit them, though I imagine the changes wouldn't last long. So it's there, but it's just grouped with all of the other "You don't much need to care here" that a lot of other parts of the Meta profile don't look at.

Comment: @Grace - so you can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log out of the parent site and you'll log out of the site's meta.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, meta for Super User (Stack Exchange site) does not have a logout.  But as ChrisF mentioned, these are not real profiles.