# Where is the logout button on the Stack Overflow site?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, logout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logout link now missing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80610/logout-link-now-missing)

For past few days, I don't see the logout option from my homepage anymore. How to logout then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your profile page new to "**Registered User**" on the right.
[image]

Comment: Don't you want to blur your email address?

Comment: @BalusC, Don't care too much...

Comment: Fair enough. Just for the case that :)

Comment: @BalusC, thanks for the warning though...